# Most efficient way to assign values to a map of maps

Tags: c++11

Given a map of maps like:

```
  std::map<unsigned int, std::map<std::string, MyBase*>> m_allMyObjects;
```

What would be the most efficient way to insert/add/"emplace" an element into m_allMyObjects given an `unsigned int` and a `std::string` taking optimization into account (on modern compilers)?

What would be the most efficient way to retrieve an element then?

m_allMyObjects may potentially contain up to 100'000 elements in the future.

Comment: Efficient for whom, the CPU or the developer? At compiletime or runtime?

Comment: Why don't you simply try all the different approaches you can think of and _measure their runtime_?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: because I think someone already did this and he could maybe share his knowledge.

Comment: The main performance problem might be the use of std::string as a key and std::map in general, but if you have to use this datastructure, what's wrong with `m_allMyObjects[key_int][key_string]=ptr_to_MyBase_Object`?

Answer (score 3):

Common knowledge and folklore about how to efficiently insert into maps (typically telling you to avoid `operator[]` and prefering the shiny new `emplace`) considers the costs of constructing and copying the *values* in the map. In your case, those values are plain pointers which can be copied at virtually no expense, and copying pointers can be aggressively optimized by the compiler.

On the other hand, you actually do have an object that is expensive to handle, namely the *key* of type `std::string`. You need to watch out for copies (moved or copied) of the key to determine performance. Obviously, for the tree lookup, you already need the string object, even if you have it as char*, as there is no insertion function that is templated over the type of key. This means for looking up the place to insert, you use one certain std::string object, but once the map node gets created, the new std::string object inside the map is copy-initialized from it (possibly moved). Avoiding everything in excess of that single copy/move should be your goal.

Example time!

```
#include <map>
#include <cstdio>

struct noisy {
  noisy(int v) : val(v) {}
  noisy(const noisy& src) : val(src.val) { std::puts("copy ctor"); }
  noisy(noisy&& src) : val(src.val)      { std::puts("move ctor"); }
  noisy& operator=(const noisy& src)
  { val = src.val; std::puts("copy assign"); return *this; }
  noisy& operator=(noisy&& src)
  { val = src.val; std::puts("move assign"); return *this; }
  int val;
};

bool operator<(const noisy& a, const noisy& b)
{
  return a.val < b.val;
}

int main(void)
{
  std::map<noisy,int> m;
  std::puts("Operator[]");
  m[noisy(1)] = 3;
  std::puts("insert/make_pair");
  m.insert(std::make_pair(noisy(2), 3));
  std::puts("insert/make_pair/ref");
  m.insert(std::make_pair<noisy&&,int>(noisy(3), 3));
  std::puts("insert/pair/ref");
  m.insert(std::pair<noisy&&,int>(noisy(4), 3));
  std::puts("emplace");
  m.emplace(noisy(5), 3);
}
```

compiled with g++ 4.9.1, -std=c++11, -O2, the result is

```
Operator[]
move ctor
insert/make_pair
move ctor
move ctor
insert/make_pair/ref
move ctor
move ctor
insert/pair/ref
move ctor
emplace
move ctor
```

Which shows: avoid everything that creates an intermediate pair containing a copy of the key! Be aware that std::make_pair does never create a pair that *contains* references, even if it can take the parameters by reference! Whenever you pass a pair containing the copy of the key, the key gets copied into the pair and later into the map.

The expression suggested by MarkMB, namely `m[int_k][str_k] = ptr`, is quite good, and likely produces optimal code. There is no reason for the first index (int_k) to not use `[]`, as you *want* a default constructed sub-map if the index is not used yet, so there is no unnecessary overhead. As we have seen, indexing with the string gets away with a single copy, so you are fine. If you can afford to lose your string, `m[int_k][std::move(str_k)] = ptr` might be a win, though. As discussed in the beginning, using `emplace` instead of `[]` is only about the values, which are virtually free to handle in your case.

Comment: wow, that an enlighting answer! Thanks a lot! I am always worried about the simplest/obvious solution in C++  not always being the best one. Thanks again.

Comment: Actually, the value is a map. That can be quite costly.

Comment: The last paragraph is about the inner map, not the outer map. The value of the inner map is a plain pointer, and handling plain pointers is virtually free. The values in the outer map are maps, you are right. But operator[] handles those maps as efficiently as possible in your case: It creates an empty map if none is present, it returns a reference to the present map if it exists. This is exactly what you need to insert into that inner map.

Comment: accessing the outer map is however super slow. I will make some more test when I have time and update this thread as it is important for the answer I believe.